# Login field validator

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have this basic JavaScript that, using a constructor, validates the form where the login fields can't be empty. All this WITHOUT using any JS libraries.

```
function Validator(txtbox) {
    this.txtbox = txtbox;
}

var validator = new Validator([ "username", "password"]);

Validator.prototype.validate = function(form) {
    for(var i = 0, l=this.txtbox.length; i < l; i++) {
        var status = document.getElementById("status-msg");
        if (form[this.txtbox[i]].value == 0) {
            status.innerHTML="The " + form[this.txtbox[i]].name + " is empty";
            status.style.display = "inline-block"
            status.className = "error";
            return false;
        }
        else {
             status.innerHTML="Login successful";
            status.style.display = "inline-block"
             status.className = "success";
        }
    }
}

function runValidate(form) {
    validator.validate(form);
}
```

I'm wondering how I can make it more efficient or better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add some [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) to your code:

```
/**
*@constructor
*@param {Array} txtbox - An array of whatever
*@returns {Validator}
*/
function Validator(txtbox) {
    /**
    *@private
    */
    this.txtbox = txtbox;
}

var validator = new Validator([ "username", "password"]);

/**
*@public
*@memberOf Validator.prototype
*@param {Form} form - The form holding the login information
*/
Validator.prototype.validate = function(form) {
    for(var i = 0, l=this.txtbox.length; i < l; i++) {
        var status = document.getElementById("status-msg");
        if (form[this.txtbox[i]].value == 0) {
            status.innerHTML="The " + form[this.txtbox[i]].name + " is empty";
            status.style.display = "inline-block"
            status.className = "error";
            return false;
        }
        else {
             status.innerHTML="Login successful";
            status.style.display = "inline-block"
             status.className = "success";
        }
    }
}

function runValidate(form) {
    validator.validate(form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Validator(txtbox) function needs to change it's parameter name. It reads like it takes a single element, but in your case you are sending an array of elements.

All your validation does is just making sure there is something in the textbox, but i could still send a whitespace string into it, and if it was asking for my phone number there's no validating if it's a valid number, or not. Or maybe it's asking for my credit card and I send in my name. There's no validation for that.

I would also set it up so that the validation function takes the actual target element as parameter.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. So a good name would be something like txtBoxArr maybe? Should I then check if the textbox is null?

Comment: Sure, or if you decide to pass an array of elements I'd go with "elements"

Comment: Ok, thanks again. When you say " actual target element as parameter" - how would I go about doing that?